# How to create configurable product programmatically in magento based on product sku ?

Tags: php, magento, import

I'm actually working on a import script to import products from a provider xml file on Magento CE 1.9.1.
Simple products are imported fine but i need to create configurable products programmatically aswell.
I would like create configurable product based on simple product Sku or a custom attribute.
For example in my provider xml i have a custom attribute called "modelcode" which is based on product sku :

```
SKU       Modelcode
123456A   123456$
123456B   123456$
123456C   123456$
```

My provider said me products with the same modelcode finishing by "$" must be assign to the same configurable product.
How could i do a configurable product programmatically based on this where the configurable product sku is the modelcode without "$" and all other attribute are the same of his "children product" except color (which is the select option) ?

Thanks